# How to post a PluralSight score from another email

Tags: support, pluralsight-iq

I accidentally followed an ad link (on SO) to PluralSight rather than a link from my SO account profile (or email), and then blundered again by using a different email from the one my SO account is registered on.  I'm not interested in spending another hour and a half taking the tests.  Is there some way to 'import' my score to SO?